# EVReflection + Moya + Realm + RxSwift - Could not create an instance for type dict

Tags: ios, swift, realm, rx-swift, moya

I'm stuck putting all of the above together. I'll appreciate if I can get any input.

Here's my short setup:

```
typealias RealmObject = Object

/// Extension to ignore undefined keys when mapping
extension RealmObject : EVReflectable {
    open override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forUndefinedKey key: String) { }
}
```

Sample Realm models:

```
class Product: RealmObject {

    dynamic var productId: String = ""  
    let productLanguages = List<ProductLanguage>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "productId"
    }
}

class ProductLanguage: RealmObject {

    dynamic var productLanguageId: String = ""
    dynamic var languageCode: String = ""
    dynamic var productName: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "productLanguageId"
    }
}
```

To fetch product details I use Moya and RxSwift:

```
func getProduct(productItemKey: String) -> Observable<Product> {
    return provider.request(.product(productId: productItemKey)).map(to: Product.self)
}
```

I think `.map(to: Product.self)` does not work with realm Lists out of the box. For each object inside the list I get an error:

```
ERROR: Could not create an instance for type 
dict:{
    CreateDate = "2015-10-12T11:11:50.013Z";
    IngredientList = "Acao ingredient";
    LanguageCode = "en-US";
    ProductId = "d6bb0084-6838-11e5-9225-00ac14ef2300";
    ProductLanguageId = "f96848d0-df77-4594-99b7-d390bb127891";
    ProductName = Acao;
    Tagline = "The smart drink - 100% organic, vegan energy booster with guara"
}
```

Is there any other way to map Moya response into Realm objects?

Thank you very much for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in EVReflection. Fixed in 4.17.0